# There is no Zero in Mathematics Digits Riddle

Tags: prolog, clpfd

This gives me:

```
?- X is 10^10//81-1.
X = 123456789.
```

So the expression delivers a number with all non-zero
digits. Is there another formula that delivers all digits,
possibly permuted, where the formula itself has no zero in it?

Can we find such a formula with Prolog or CLP(FD)?

Comment: X is (9+1)^(9+1)//81-1. ?

Comment: What are the odds that there is a shorter formula?

Comment: The odds are good if you allow `X is 123456789/1.` or `X is 246913578/2.`

Answer (score 1):

SWI-Prolog gives me:

```
?- use_module(library(clpfd)).
true.
 
?- [D1,D2,D3,D4,D5,D6,D7,D8,D9] ins 1..9, 
   [A,B,C] ins 2..9\/11..15, 
   A^B*C #= (((((((D1*10+D2)*10+D3)*10+D4)*10+D5)*10+D6)*10+D7)*10+D8)*10+D9, 
   all_different([D1,D2,D3,D4,D5,D6,D7,D8,D9]), 
   label([A,B,C,D1,D2,D3,D4,D5,D6,D7,D8,D9]).
D1 = C, C = 9,
D2 = 4,
D3 = 8,
D4 = B, B = 7,
D5 = 2,
D6 = 1,
D7 = 5,
D8 = 3,
D9 = 6,
A = 14 ;
false.
 
?- X is 14^7*9.
X = 948721536.
```